# Substring with offset going reverse

Tags: string, perl, substring

I looked at documentation of substr in Perl and see the 'offset' which is the position to start and 'length' is how long. If 'length' is negative, that's how many characters to leave off the right end of the string. How do I get a substring **before** the 'offset'? Example

```
my $string = "HelloWorld";
my $sub = someFunction(string=$string, offset=5, lengthBefore=2); # I know this is not Perl syntax for sub-routine but wanted to show the inputs I need
print "$sub\n";
```

I want to get

```
oW
```

Is there a function to do this in Perl? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Re "*How do I get a substring before the 'offset'?*", Technically, that's not 2 before position 5; that's 2 before position 6. That's a confusing interface.

Comment: `($string =~ /^..{5}(?<=(.{2}))/s)[0]`

Comment: @ikegami Sorry, I meant to say I wanted a sub routine like substr but going the opposite way. Because using substr($string, 5, 2) would give 'Wo'. Hm, now that I think about it, probably not the best example string to use... but thanks! Will accept your answer as it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sub someFunction {
   my ($s, $i, $j) = @_;
   my $start = $i-$j+1;
   $start = 0 if $start < 0;
   my $length = $i-$start+1;
   return substr($s, $start, $length);
}
```

or

```
sub someFunction {
   my ($s, $i, $j) = @_;
   return substr(substr($s, 0, $i+1), -$j);
}
```

That assumes that `someFunction("012345", 2, 4)` should return `012`.